# PHP Mysqli - editing records but items are cut off

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a CRUD system and on my edit page, its retrieving the data but the records are cut off after the first space.

For example, if the database record says *Stack Overflow* within the company column and i use the code below, i only get the word *Stack* instead of *Stack Overflow*.

```
<?php
  include_once("connection.php");
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM leads WHERE id=$id");
  while ($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $company  = $res['company'];
  }
?>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="company" name="company" placeholder="Company" required value=<?php echo $company;?>>
```

Why is it just pulling the first word?

Comment: surround your <?php echo $company;?> with quotes.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the quotes in your html code:

**Wrong**

```
value=<?php echo $company;?>>
```

**Correct**

```
value="<?php echo $company;?>">
```

Answer (score -1):

Also, if you want to avoid any issues with company names that contain `"` you should probably escape double quotes using htmlentities.

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="company" name="company" placeholder="Company"  required value="<?php echo htmlentities($company, ENT_COMPAT); ?>">
```